# Where can I find the 'of the Wild' set?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've completed all of the shrines and I was informed that my gift from the sages is in a temple somewhere (can't really remember where exactly).

So, when you have done all of the shrines, where will the 'of the Wild' armor set be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this article](https://samurai-gamers.com/legend-zelda-breath-wild/the-wild-armor-set-guide/), you will find the set in the Forgotten Temple.

> All pieces of the armor set can be found in The Forgotten Temple.

From the [page about the quest which rewards this armor set](https://samurai-gamers.com/legend-zelda-breath-wild/gift-monks-walkthrough/):

> The reward which is an “of the Wild” armor set lies waiting at the foot of the Goddess Statue placed behind the local shrine.

For directions to the Forgotten Temple, here's where the [wikia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Forgotten_Temple) says it is:

> It is a large building found at the northernmost end of Tanagar Canyon.

Comment: I guess the OP forgot about the Forgotten Temple

Comment: As had I, when I went to get the set I headed back to the temple of Time ruins where you first get the paraglider and was surprised when it was not there. I think if you check the quest that the monk gives you to get your gear it has a way-point marker showing where to go, but its been a while since I got the set.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the 'of the Wild' set in the Forgotten Temple behind the Rona Kachta Shrine in the Tabantha Region.

[image: Map with Shrine location]

[Location on interactive map.](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/breath-of-the-wild-interactive-map/?id=Rona%20Kachta%20Shrine)

Since you have already completed all the shrines you can just warp directly to Rona Kachta shrine and pick up your goodies. I wouldn't recommend traveling there on foot as there are a large number of guardians protecting the way.